# api retry attempt after timer expires

Tags: python, api

I am using Python to access a building automation system thru a restful API connection and I am running into a problem where it appears I am  not receiving an update which is the value of a temperature sensor. It seems like it works 90% of the time and every once and while I feel like I need some sort of a retry attempt in the code. No exception is thrown, it seems like the code just sits forever in a waiting mode. This method below is how I receive the updated value from the sensor:

```
def getState(self):

    sensor = session.find_entity(filter_expr='dat2', single=True) 
    sensor.wait()
    sensor = sensor.result
    sensor = float(sensor.tags['curVal'])
    return sensor
```

The package that I use is called pyhaystack, and in the [readthedocs](https://pyhaystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/site.html) under operands there is a section for how to write asynchronous exceptions except I am not running into any exceptions, and sorry there is not a lot of API wisdom here either...

In the screenshot below this is after a keyboard interrupt after the code sits all night long waiting. I wrote the custom_env.py file but everything else below that is part of the pyhaystack package.

[image]

I know the code below isn't correct as it will never reach the `for i in range` if its hung on the `sensor.wait()`, but is it possible to create some sort of a timer that if a response isn't received within 30 seconds then retry... Something like:

```
def getState(self):

    sensor = session.find_entity(filter_expr='dat2', single=True) 
    sensor.wait()

    n=30
    for i in range(n)
        time.sleep(1)
        n-=1

        if n=0 and sensor.wait():#didnt work, retry
                sensor = session.find_entity(filter_expr='dat2', single=True) 
                sensor.wait()

        else:
            pass

    sensor = sensor.result
    sensor = float(sensor.tags['curVal'])
    return sensor
```

Any tips help! Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: ...to create some sort of a timer that if a response isn't received within 30 seconds

According to the docs, you could use `wait.(timeout=30)`

---

> From the Documentation:
>
> ```
> pyhaystack.util.state.HaystackOperation.wait():
> ```
>
> - This blocks the current thread until the operation completes (or if timeout is specified, until that number of seconds expires).

---

> ```
> wait(timeout=None)
> ```
>
> - Wait for an operation to finish. This should NOT be called in the same thread as the thread executing the operation as this will deadlock.

Comment: Could you elaborate this more on NOT being used in the same thread? I think this maybe my issue... I wonder if I remove the `.wait()` from my function that it could resolve the issue?

Comment: *"NOT being used in the same thread"*: This means, `wait(...` is **blocking**, maybe forever or until the `timeout`. Therefore it's recommend to run it in a own `thread`.

Comment: Ah ok, I think get it.... So to create another thread I need to create a separate connection to the building automation. Like another Python class .py file dedicated for this method/function... Sorry I am still riding the learning curve :)